# Is there a method of creating a bundle of bundles?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to load the minimum number of files per page without a lot of redundant code in my BundleConfig.cs file.

```
var thirdPartyScriptBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/core").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",                   // JQuery Core
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",                          // Bootstrap
            "~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js",                 // Knockout
            "~/Scripts/underscore.js",                         // Underscore
            "~/Scripts/moment.js"                              // Moment
            );
bundles.Add(thirdPartyScriptBundle);

var page1SpecificScriptBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/page1").Include(
            "~/Scripts/page1.js"
            );
bundles.Add(page1SpecificScriptBundle);


var page1MergedScriptBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/page1merged")
            .Include("~/bundle/core")
            .Include("~/bundle/page1");
bundles.Add(page1MergedScriptBundle );
```

Unfortunately, when `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/page1merged")` is added to a view, no javascript file is included.

With `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false` I expect my html to include:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>   
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
...
<script src="/Scripts/page1.js"></script>
```

But the html is blank in that spot.

With `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true`, I see

```
<script src="/bundle/page1merged"></script>
```

But watching the network traffic, the file itself is empty.

Does anyone have a solution to make this work?  Today, my site has a number of different pages each using a unique combination of bundles.  Rather than have each page load up to 7 bundles, I'd like to find a way to combine it into 1 script bundle and 1 css bundle per page.

I'll take an alternate solution if someone has one too.

Comment: First of all, `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/landingmerge") ` is not there in your code. so obviously you can't render it. For bundling to work, you need to have `EnableOptimizations` to true. So basically i did not understood your question about large scale website and files.

Comment: sorry about that.  bad cut and paste error.  I updated the name of the merged bundle I'm trying to render in my page for clarification.  The merged bundle does not exist both with or without optimizations turned on.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple edits on the question.  I've been banging my head against this for a few hours.  I think the current edit I have accurately conveys my issue.  Using ~/bundle/page1merged does not work.

Comment: Have you tried by loading individual bundles? Instead of creating `bundle of bundles`, and also you cannot `include` bundles in another bundle. `include` method takes virtualpaths of physical files.

Comment: `Rather than have each page load up to 7 bundles` that is not true. Your `JS` and `CSS` files can be cached by browser and subsequent requests will not be made every time, unless you can content in any of the file in a bundle. So I think there is no need for you to worry about loading of multiple bundles for performance.